# Fill listview from fragment

Tags: android, listview

I have a layout file containing a listview that I would like to fill with the help of a Fragment. But it continues to give me errors.
The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_patient_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_patient_button" />
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragmentActivity:

```
public class BasicFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.create_patient_view);

    FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list);

    if (fragment == null) {


        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.list, new BasicFragment());
        ft.commit(); // Make sure you call commit or your Fragment will not be added. 
                     // This is very common mistake when working with Fragments!
    }
}

}
```

My ListFragment:

```
public class BasicFragment extends ListFragment {

private PatientAdapter pAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    pAdapter = new PatientAdapter(getActivity(), GFRApplication.dPatients);
    setListAdapter(pAdapter);
}
}
```

The error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findFragmentById(...)` function takes ID of fragment(!) as parameter. But you call it with `R.id.list` which is `ID` of ListView (`<ListView android:id="@+id/list" ...`). It's wrong because `ListView` is NOT a fragment. It's the first problem.

The second problem is:

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
       ft.add(R.id.list, new BasicFragment());
```

in `ft.add()` function first parameter is ID of container in which you want to put your fragment. But you use `R.id.list` which is id of your `ListView`. It is wrong because ListView is not a container in which you can put fragments directly.

If you want put fragments into `ListView` items you can:

1. fill `ListView` with custom views.
2. declare `<fragment ...>` into custom view layout (XML). Or create fragment container in custom view layout (FrameLayout for example) and put there fragment at runtime (in getView() method).

Comment: I had already tried it that way, but somehow when I tried it this time it worked. Thanks for the pointer :)